# Query with a few subqueries and appropriate indicies taking, on average, 613ms to execute

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, query-performance

I have a ton of queries that do a similar thing as to what I'm doing here, but none of them have the performance issues this one does:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT lead_id FROM leads WHERE to_id = lead_id OR from_id = lead_id) as lead_id, 
  (SELECT CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) FROM leads WHERE to_id = lead_id OR from_id = lead_id) as lead_name 
FROM 
  text_messages t 
WHERE sent_to_number = "xxx" OR sent_from_number = "xxx" 
  AND organization = 1 GROUP BY lead_id ORDER BY sent_at DESC;
```

That query right there takes on average 613ms to execute.

I have indicies on from_id, to_id, sent_to_number, and sent_from_number.

Why is this query taking so long to execute?

### EDIT:

Added in `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+-------------+------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type        | possible_keys                      | key                   | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                                                            |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+-------------+------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | t     | NULL       | index_merge | organization,from_number,to_number | to_number,from_number | 62,62   | NULL |   83 |   100.00 | Using union(to_number,from_number); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | leads | NULL       | ALL         | PRIMARY                            | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL | 7910 |    19.00 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)                                   |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | leads | NULL       | ALL         | PRIMARY                            | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL | 7910 |    19.00 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)                                   |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+-------------+------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### Edit 2:

Server Spec:
Cloud SQL - MySQL 5.7 - 1 CPU - 3.75 GB RAM - 100 GB SSD

Comment: Why do you think 613 milliseconds is too long? What's your expectation and why? Also,  [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: @Vérace about 8k

Comment: @Vérace added in "Explain Extended". By the way - This is amazing!!! I never knew about this before. I'm not sure how to interpret it right now, but it's way cool!

Comment: @Vérace So both of those already have indicies on them. I'll add server spec right now, but we are in Cloud SQL in the Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: **And** you have an SSD? There's something wrong somewhere - for 8k records, I'd expect 1-2 milliseconds max. Experiment with an index on organization and sent_at - however it's still strange that such a relatively simple query should take so long for only 8k records. Have you tried running the subqueries independently? Maybe a case for contacting GCP support? Is there support?

Comment: The ORs are killing performance.  Perhaps using UNIONs would help.  Need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the table sizes to give further specifics.

Comment: When using multiple tables, please qualify each column so that we can tell which table they are in.

Answer (score 0):

Your query plan shows two table scans on `leads`, which is not surprising given the search predicates with `OR`: `FROM leads WHERE to_id = lead_id OR from_id = lead_id`.

It also shows a spilled sort, suggesting that the sort buffer is too small.

Consider rewriting your query with joins instead of subselects, something like:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(leads_to.lead_id, leads_from.lead_id) as lead_id, 
  COALESCE(CONCAT(leads_to.first_name, " ", leads_to.last_name), CONCAT(leads_from.first_name, " ", leads_from.last_name)) as lead_name 
FROM 
  text_messages t 
LEFT JOIN leads leads_to ON to_id = leads_to.lead_id
LEFT JOIN leads leads_from ON to_id = leads_from.lead_id
WHERE sent_to_number = "xxx" OR sent_from_number = "xxx" 
  AND organization = 1 GROUP BY lead_id ORDER BY sent_at DESC
```

To address the sort spill try increasing `sort_buffer_size`.